# Getting a "Error Connecting to server (111): Connection refused" from CloudAMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, cloudamqp

I am prototyping a message queue solution developed using CodeIgniter. The code is hosted on a GoDaddy basic shared hosting plan and connects to a trial instance of RabbitMQ on CloudAMQP. I use the videlalvaro/php-amqplib library.

The solution worked fine for a few days and yesterday I started getting a connection refused error. No changes to the code, in fact the same code running on my local machine works fine and connects to CloudAMQP.

This leads me to believe that the problem could be with GoDaddy hosting. Have spent about 48 hours trying to work around this and my project is now stalled.

Does anyone have any ideas? My only option now is to move to a different hosting service and try but that's a major step and I wanted to be sure I'm not missing something small.

The relevant part of the code below:

```
$url = parse_url("amqp://yyyyyyyy:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@moose.rmq.cloudamqp.com/yyyyyyyy");
//Masking the user name and password for here
$conn = new AMQPStreamConnection(
    $url['host'], //host - CloudAMQP_URL 
    5672,         //port - port number of the service, 5672 is the default
    $url['user'], //user - username to connect to server
    $url['pass'], //password - password to connect to the server
    substr($url['path'], 1) //vhost
);
```

Comment: Whe does CloudAMQP support says? Are url credentials valid?

Comment: Support says they could find no problem. And the credentials are valid. The setup works on my local machine. Which is what is making it so hard to debug.

Comment: Try top open connection to target machine with telnet or use some low-level tool, like from librabbitmq toolchain. See this link - http://rubybunny.info/articles/troubleshooting.html, it may come in handy.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful. I passed on the suggestion to GoDaddy to use telnet to test and they say it does not connect because they do not allow such connections from shared servers. Not sure why it worked earlier for two weeks, maybe they blocked the ports later. But they were not clear about it. GoDaddy support gets no stars from me.

Comment: JFYI: there are official RabbitMQ user group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users, give it a try, it has a lot of things already answered and discussed.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may face a similar problem, this could have been because of hosting on GoDaddy (could apply to any hosting service) where presumably access to post 5672 is not allowed. I moved to AWS and everything is working fine.

This question can be closed (not sure how that happens).

Thank you zaq178miami, your inputs helped.